# Hide IBM Application Server Message That Appeared on browser

Tags: security, browser, websphere

Environment Details :

1- Application Server : IBM Application Server 7.0.11

2- Web Server : IBM HTTP Server ( IHS ) .

When I requested stopped application for example : TETS1 the below error appeared on browser :

---

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /TETS1 has not been defined.

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle 192.160.107.11:80 has not been defined.

IBM WebSphere Application Server

---

How can avoid the above message to appeared on browser ( for security wise )

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a custom property which says the server is under maintenance.

For example:

Go to your appserver console -> click on servers -> server types -> application servers -> server1 -> webcontainer settings ->webcontainer -> custom properties -> click on new and add custom property.

Give Name : `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webgroupvhostnotfound` 
value : Server is under Maintenance, we regret any inconvenience caused

save this and restart server instance `[server1]`

That's it.. If your application is down, the error message, which you configured in custom property, will display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This error that you're getting is the default error generated by WebSphere when no web application is bound to the requested context root (in your case, `/TETS1`).

WebSphere is sending this text back to the client along with HTTP code 404 (Not Found).

The only way for you to override what's being shown to the client is by configuring IHS to display a particular page whenever the response, coming back from WAS, is HTTP 404.

Comment: Thank you Isaac but How I can do that ?

Comment: using the `ErrorDocument` directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/custom-error.html